# Piping input from user into the shell to run commands

Tags: c, shell

I have a basic shell written in C started, but am stuck on taking user input and piping that into the shell. I want the string variable `current_command` to be piped into a working shell.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

//for Ptrace:
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>

void type_prompt();

#define TRUE 1
#define CHAR_MAX 100 //set max string length to 9
#define CMND_ARGS_MAX 9 // maximum 9 arguments for command
int main(void)
{
   //command is a string with max length 100
   //params is a 2d array; 9 possible arguments, each being a str with max len 100
   char command[CHAR_MAX] , params[CMND_ARGS_MAX][CHAR_MAX];

   printf("Hello, World\n");
    char buf[128]; //max lenght of date string = 128 chars
    struct tm *today;
    time_t now;

    time(&now);
    today=localtime(&now);

    strftime(buf,128,"%d/%m/%Y",today);
    printf("Today is %s\n",buf);

    int pid, status;


    char current_command[100];


    while(TRUE) { 
        printf("Enter 'exit' to exit into the shell\n$");
        scanf("%s", current_command); //PIPE THIS INTO SHELL
        printf("%s\n", current_command);

        if(strcmp("exit", current_command) == 0) {
          printf("\n\n~~~~~Welcome to the shell~~~~~\n\n$");

          break;
        }

        pid_t child;
        long orig_eax;
        child = fork();
        if(child == 0) { 
            printf("Ptrace executing...\n");
            ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
            execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
        }
        else {
            wait(NULL);
            orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                              child, 4 * ORIG_RAX,
                              NULL);
            printf("The child made a "
                   "system call %ld\n", orig_eax);

            ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child, NULL, NULL); //put into program()
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to make a shell but you want to use a shell. What?

Comment: I've been following tutorials to implement my own shell in C, but I am stuck at this point. What I'm trying to do now is take user input (from `current_command`) and pipe that to the appropriate place to execute a shell command. Would it be somewhere like /bin/sh or something?

Comment: It sounds like you want to open another process, send data into its standard-in, and collect data from its standard-out. Do some searching on this and perhaps re-frame your question.

Answer (score 0):

The job of a shell *is* to take a command and run it. If you're implementing a shell, you can't just take a command and send it to `/bin/sh`, since that *is* a shell too. The full explanation is out of scope, but the basic idea is:

1. `fork()` so that there is a parent and child process
2. In the child process, use `exec()` to replace the current process with the user-supplied program
3. In the parent, use `wait()` to determine when the child process exits.

A more detailed explanation and sample code can be found [here](https://brennan.io/2015/01/16/write-a-shell-in-c/) (disclaimer - I wrote it).

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand very well your question.
I understood you want to make a shell, and you have some problems with redirections.

I think you already know how to use fork(), wait() and execve()
I suggest you to also read the man of [dup2](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man2/dup.2.html).

dup2() will take 2 fd in parameters.
Don't hesitate to just make a shitty test to try to execute "ls -l | cat -e", for example.

You made me realize I completely forgot how I made my shell, just 5-6 months ago ! :')

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

To send some input to a program, you need to pipe its stdin.

Basically you want to create a pipe using `pipe()`, then `fork()`, then `dup2()` in child. Let's say you piped an `int fd[2]`, so you will need to call `dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO)` (child proc), and from the main process: write to the writing end of the pipe: `write(fd[1], current_command, strlen(current_command);` then `wait`.

I'm not an expert, but this is the main idea.